# Send Node.js app logs located at Heroku to file

Tags: javascript, heroku, logging

I have problem with sending Node.js app logs located at Heroku to file. I'm using well known [logger](https://www.npmjs.com/package/logger). When I clone code from Heroku to my local computer logfile is empty. No errors. Application opened on local server sends logs to file with no problems. Where is mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Heroku's ephemeral filesystem](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem) makes logging to a file impractical. Any changes you make to it, e.g. adding or modifying files, will be lost whenever your dyno restarts. This [happens frequently](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#automatic-dyno-restarts) (at least once per day).

Even if this weren't the case, if you clone from Heroku the log files wouldn't be included since they're not committed to your repository. (This is good—log files should never be tracked.)

Your best bet for having persistent, long-term logs is to use a [logging addon](https://elements.heroku.com/addons#logging) or set up a [log drain](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/log-drains).

Finally, note that [cloning from Heroku is an anti-pattern](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git-clone-heroku-app):

> Heroku provides the git service primarily for deployment, and the ability to clone from it is offered as a convenience. We strongly recommend you store your code in another git repository such as [GitHub](https://github.com/) and treat that as canonical.